# Checking dependency of variables in a contingency table

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to know if what I understood in class is right, and it's something regarding the verification of dependence between variables in a contingency table.

[image]

According to what I understood in class, if there is independence between the variables then:

$f_{ij} = f_{i \cdot} \times f_{\cdot j}$

Should be true for each cell, if it is false for one or more cell, then there is dependency between the variables.

So, let's check when $i = 1$, and $j = 1$.

$f_{11} = \frac{42}{100}$

$f_{1\cdot} = \frac{52}{100}$

$f_{\cdot 1} = \frac{51}{100}$

Because $\frac{42}{100} \neq \frac{52}{100} \cdot \frac{51}{100}$ we can say that there's dependence, I'm right?

I ask because I feel I didn't understand well what the teacher said and also I find that it's almost impossible that $f_{ij} = f_{i \cdot} \times f_{\cdot j}$ is satisfied for each cell.

Answer (score 1):

**A 'population' of 100 animals.** If your population has only 100 animals, and your probability
structure is based only on those 100, then you could divide
the count in each cell by 100 to get probabilities. In that
case your answer would be correct.

**A sample of 100 animals.**
However, it seems more likely to me that this is a sample
of size 100 from a larger population of animals and you
want to test whether categorical variable Gender (M/F) is
independent of categorical Species (cat/dog) in the population.

**Statistical tests of independence.** There are two common procedures to test the null hypothesis
that these two variables are independent against the alternative
that they are not. One method is called the Fisher Exact Test
and it is based on the hypergeometric distribution. The other
method is a chi-squared test for independence and it is based
on a statistic that has approximately the chi-squared distribution
with 1 degree of freedom. If you are supposed to one of these
tests, you can find explanations of them in a statistics textbook
or online.

**Brief view of the ch-squared test of independence.** The chi-squared test is based on an idea very much like the one
you show. Consider the top left cell for 'Dog and Male' 
We estimate the probability of Dog is this population as 52/100 and the probability of Male as 51/100. Under the hypothesis of
independence the probability of both Dog and Male is estimated
by the product  0.2652. Based on this assumption, we would
have $E_{11} = 0.2652(100) = 26.52$ as the estimated count
in the upper left cell. But we actually see $X_{11} = 42.$ Intuitively,
this is not good agreement, and tends to make us disbelieve
independence of Gender and Species. 
A common measure of the disagreement in this cell is $Q_{11} = (X_{11} - E_{11})^2/E_{11} = 9.036.$

For a formal test, one does this same procedure for each cell
and adds the four $Q_{ij}$ together, for an overall chi-squared
statistic. If this total is greater than 3.85 we reject the
null hypothesis of independence at the '5% level of significance'.
(The number 3.85 cuts off 5% of the area from the right tail of the density
function of a chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom.)

I used software to get the total 38.4, which is hugely larger
than 3.85, so it seem pretty clear that Gender and Species are
associated rather than independent categorical variables in the
population from which your sample of 100 animals was randomly chosen.
Perhaps these are pets sampled at vet clinics. If so, the
clients tend to prefer male dogs and female cats.